# Can I assign a Type to a class variable based on a generic type in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating some components dynamically using Angular's module factory:

```
const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(moduleRef.instance.widgetComponent);
const componentRef = container.createComponent(compFactory);
```

I have an abstract class that defines the widget to create, and some additional methods that I have removed here, where `T` is the Angular component:

```
export abstract class WebPartBaseModule<T extends ComponentWidgetBase> { 
  abstract widgetComponent;
}
```

Then in my derived class modules I explicitly set the component I need:

```
export class HealthCheckModule extends WebPartBaseModule<HealthCheckComponent> {
  widgetComponent = HealthCheckComponent;
}
```

This works well, but Im wondering if there is a way to infer/assign the type in the base class from `T`. This is what I'm after since then I would not need to assign the `widgetComponent` in each derived class, but its obviously not working:

```
export abstract class WebPartBaseModule<T extends ComponentWidgetBase> { 
  widgetComponent = T;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're using `widgetComponent` in the abstract class? Maybe you can just use `T` directly?

Comment: Its not used in the class directly, its called by: moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(moduleRef.instance.widgetComponent);

Comment: I'll clarify the above though, while widgetComponent is not used directly, T is used in an init method:  public initComponent(component: T, path: string): void {
  //init common to all components derived from ComponentWidgetBase
    }

Comment: In export class HealthCheckModule extends WebPartBaseModule<HealthCheckComponent> {
  widgetComponent = HealthCheckComponent;
}

where is HealthCheckComponent coming from?

Comment: Its an angular component defined in a separate class:  import { HealthCheckComponent } from './health-check.component';